# Loading scss files in Storybook & Angular: expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, sass, storybook

I'm trying to setup storybook for my angular project. However, when trying to setup the first story for a component, i got the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/modules/ka-basic-components/ka-button/ka-button.component.scss
Module build failed:
@import '~styles/helpers/variables';
^
  File to import not found or unreadable: ~styles/helpers/variables.
```

I then added a webpack config with the following rules:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
        include: __dirname
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'fonts/[hash].[ext]',
            limit: 5000,
            mimetype: 'application/font-woff'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|png)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'fonts/[hash].[ext]'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Now, i get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/modules/ka-basic-components/ka-button/ka-button.component.scss
Module build failed:
@import '~styles/helpers/variables';
^
      Invalid CSS after "": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"
```

My researched showed this error commonly means that there exist multiple tests for .scss, however i don't have any other webpack configs. I'm using the default storybook configs and this is my index.stories.ts:

```
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/angular';
import { text, boolean } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';
import { KaButtonComponent } from '../app/modules/ka-basic-components/ka-button/ka-button.component';

storiesOf('Button', module).add('Primary', () => ({
    component: KaButtonComponent,
    props: {
        text: text('text', 'Button text'),
        disabled: boolean('disabled', true)
    },
    moduleMetadata: {}
}));
```

Does anybody have any idea where this error could come from and how i can fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that webpack did not know how to handle the ~styles bit of the import statement in the scss file. The solution is to define the alias in the webpack config and leave out the scss loader:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            styles: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles')
        }
    }
};
```